# Instantiate Oracle datasource with wallet without specifying username and password

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, datasource, oracle-call-interface

I have this datasource, that works fine if I specify username, password and url.

```
        public Connection dataSource() throws SQLException {
          OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
          dataSource.setUser(userName);
          dataSource.setPassword(password);
          dataSource.setURL(url);
          return dataSource;
        }
```

How can I set the oracle datasource if I have the wallet address of database?

```
jdbc:oracle:oci:@//<ip>:<port>/<db>
```

I tried this but it's not working, because login fail (I have returned username password don't match)

```
public Connection dataSource() throws SQLException {
          OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
          dataSource.setURL(wallet);
          return dataSource;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must manually define the wallet in the JDBC URL, e.g. `jdbc:oracle:thin:@service_name?TNS_ADMIN=wallet`. For example, let's say the wallet is located on your system at the following directory: `/Oracle/ADWC/adwc_sales`. You would then define your connection as `jdbc:oracle:thin:@adwc_sales_low?TNS_ADMIN=/Oracle/ADWC/adwc_sales`, where @adwc_sales_low is a defined connection in your TNSNAMES.ora file and the TNS_ADMIN field pointed to the directory where the client credentials were unzipped.

You can find more information here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html